# move buttons in order

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

sorry for bad english. 
i want to move buttons in order after press RUN.
In this sense, when run algorithm i want move button step by step.
for example move 13, then 14, then 15
    [puzzle](http://upload7.ir/uploads//2b914db521d0ba884eddfd5b201fd71bc1169922.jpg)

i try everything and i tired :(

```
    public static class StoryboardExtensions
    {
        public static async Task BeginAsync(this Storyboard storyboard)
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<bool> tb = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            EventHandler onComplete = null;
            onComplete = (s, e) =>
            {
                storyboard.Completed -= onComplete;
                tb.SetResult(true);
            };
            storyboard.Completed += onComplete;
            storyboard.Begin();
            await tb.Task;
        }
    }
```

i try await and async but not work,after complete algorithm move all buttons together, not move buttons in order

for one button in xaml file:

```
    <Button Name="butt1" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="70" Height="70" >
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Name="stor1">
                        <ThicknessAnimation Name="thic1" Storyboard.TargetName="butt1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                            Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

in .cs file, first i try await async but not work then i comment them

```
    public void stor_Completed(string num, char direction)
    {
        Button butt = (Button)this.FindName("butt" + num);
        Storyboard stor = (Storyboard)this.FindName("stor" + num);
        ThicknessAnimation thic = (ThicknessAnimation)this.FindName("thic" + num);
        thic.From = butt.Margin;
        thic.To = null;
        //thic.By = null;
        TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
        tt.X = butt.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetX;
        tt.Y = butt.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetY;

        if (direction == 'U')
        {
            thic.By = new Thickness(0, -80, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (direction == 'D')
        {
            thic.By = new Thickness(0, 80, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (direction == 'R')
        {
            thic.By = new Thickness(80, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (direction == 'L')
        {
            thic.By = new Thickness(-80, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        stor.Children.Add(thic);
        stor.Begin();

        //await stor.BeginAsync();        //or tow next line
        //Task tcs = StoryboardExtensions.BeginAsync(stor);
        //await tcs;
    }
```

i call this function:

```
    stor_Completed((matrix[indexOf16]).ToString(), 'L');
```

please help me

Comment: *i try await and async but not work* What do you mean by *not work*? What happens? Any compiler error? Runtime exception? or?

Comment: no compiler error, no runtime exception, after complete algorithm move all button together, i want move in order

Comment: Ok, what happens then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited version**

The `class StoryboardExtension` looks fine, but you should change `stor_Completed` like this:

```
        public async void AnimationInSequence()
        {    
            await stor_Completed("13", 'L').BeginAsync();
            await stor_Completed("10", 'D').BeginAsync();
            await stor_Completed("9", 'R').BeginAsync();   
        }

        public Storyboard stor_Completed(string num, char direction)
        {
            Button butt = (Button)this.FindName("butt" + num);
            Storyboard stor = (Storyboard)this.FindName("stor" + num);
            ThicknessAnimation thic = (ThicknessAnimation)this.FindName("thic" + num);
            thic.From = butt.Margin;
            thic.To = null;
            //thic.By = null;
            TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
            tt.X = butt.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetX;
            tt.Y = butt.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetY;

            if (direction == 'U')
            {
                thic.By = new Thickness(0, -80, 0, 0);
            }
            else if (direction == 'D')
            {
                thic.By = new Thickness(0, 80, 0, 0);
            }
            else if (direction == 'R')
            {
                thic.By = new Thickness(80, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            else if (direction == 'L')
            {
                thic.By = new Thickness(-80, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            stor.Children.Add(thic);
            return stor;
        }
```

Please note, I've just *tested* my code in this edit, and *it works as expected* (storyboard animation in sequence)

The complete project is in [this repository](https://github.com/giuliohome/Net4.5/blob/master/Sync/WpfApplication1/MainWindow.xaml.cs)

Click on Questions => buttons move together (your code)

Click on Solution => they move step by step (my code)

Comment: i try this but freeze the program in line `tb.Task.Wait();`

Comment: i think problem is program do not enter into event ocomplete `onComplete = (s, e) =>
            {
                storyboard.Completed -= onComplete;
                tb.SetResult(true);
            };`

Comment: have a look at my edit, where I'm suggesting an alternative fix

Comment: code fixed and working as expected now: please confirm, thanks

Comment: so thanks for solution, i try it, but not work, move button together, not step by step :(

Comment: I'm really sure they move step by step! Have you copied my source? I can upload the whole project then....

Comment: The whole source is on [GitHub here](https://github.com/giuliohome/Net4.5/blob/master/Sync/WpfApplication1/MainWindow.xaml.cs)

Comment: your code is worked, but see my [code](http://www.mediafire.com/download/3d8194g5luik60r/Puzzle_15.rar), i call AnimationInSequence for each button, no call at one time

Comment: That is the problem in your code. You have to use async/await like that. It should be easy to re-engineer your solution.

Comment: Just move the sync and await to the caller module. Post a complete project or a bigger part if you need help in doing this rework.

Comment: Oh... You posted a link above. I will download and check it later, and if that is your complete code, I will reply with a new version of it